# React Native: New screen after touching image using stack navigator

Tags: react-native, expo, stack-navigator, onpress, touchablewithoutfeedback

I am trying to learn `React Native` by creating an app. After I touch an image I want a new screen to be placed on top of the current screen.

I think I want to use a `StackNavigator` after `onPress`? I've read about them but don't know how to use them with my current code. Any ideas??

```
const listView = ({name, picture}) => { 
       return (  
        <View style = {styles.item}>  
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => //new screen here!!}>  
            <ImageBackground source = {picture}  
                             resizeMode = 'cover'  
                             style={styles.image}>  
                <Text style={styles.text}>{name}</Text>  
            </ImageBackground>  
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>  
        </View>  
      )  
};
```

Please leave any questions you need in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Createrestacknavigator.`

exampleApp.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
} from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./Home.js"
import Second from "./Second.js"
...
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },
    Second: {
      screen: Second
    }   
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default AppContainer;
```

exampleHome.js:

```js
 return (  
        <View style = {styles.item}>  
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Second")}>  
            <ImageBackground source = {picture}  
                             resizeMode = 'cover'  
                             style={styles.image}>  
                <Text style={styles.text}>{name}</Text>  
            </ImageBackground>  
            </TouchableOpacity >  
        </View>  
      )
```

See [this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) for more information on features.